# JQuery(JavaScript)+PHP syntax explanation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Going through some exercise which including JQuery  + PHP  combined together .The part I am not completely understand is in the Jquery code when the if statement starts  ,can someone please explain from this point on what's going on?

HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post"> 
            <label for="name">Name:</label><br> 
            <input type="text" name="name"><br><br> 
            <label for="email">Email:</label><br> 
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off"><br><br> 
            <label for="password">Password:</label><br> 
            <input type="text" name="password"><br><br> 
            <input type ="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up"> 
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

if(! empty($_GET['email'])){ 

    $email=filter_var($_GET['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); 

    if($email){ 

        $con="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=eshop;charset=utf8"; 
        $db= new PDO($con,'root',''); 
        $query=$db->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?"); 
        $query->execute([$email]); 
        $email=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

        if($email){ 

            echo true; 
        }
    }
}
```

JQuery code:

```
$('#email').on('keyup', function(){ 

    var userEmail= $(this).val().trim(); 
    $('#result').remove(); 
    var emailRegex= /^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i; 

    if(emailRegex.test(userEmail)){ 
        $.get('check_email.php',{email:userEmail},function(res){ 

            if(res ==1){ 

                $('#email').after('<span id="result">*Email is taken</span>');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: if userEmail matches the regular expression then send a get request to check_email.php with the parameter email with the value from userEmail. If the response equals 1 (this scripts way of saying the email is taken) then add a span element with the text email is taken after the email element

Comment: Can you please explain the $.get('check_email.php',{email:userEmail},function(res) ...stage by stage I just came across this and I don't understand the syntax of it

Comment: Why do we pass a parameter to check_email.php?

Comment: Because the PHP-file needs an email to check. The request to check is done after the email is deemed valid as an email with the regex. What is the problem here, really?

Comment: @ValerieKurt https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/